# RadioListTile not checked

Tags: flutter, dart

RadioListTile can't checked with callback. groupValue is QuestionId,
value has 1 to 4 on each question. stuck on this for a day.
`setState((){ groupValue=value });` on void Call back
[image: app UI]

```
 ListView showAnswerChoice(List<ExamQuestionModel> qa) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: qa.length,
      shrinkWrap: true,
      physics: const ScrollPhysics(),
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int i) {
        _radioGroupValue = qa[i].qId;
        return Stack(
          children: [
            Card(
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                side: const BorderSide(width: 1, color: Colors.black),
              ),
              child: Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    HtmlWidget(qa[i].qTextQuestion),
                    ExamRadioButton(
                      question: qa[i],
                      value: 1,
                      gpValue: qa[i].qId,
                      title: qa[i].qChoiceA,
                      onSelected: userChooseAnswer,
                    ),
                    qa[i].qChoiceB != ""
                        ? ExamRadioButton(
                            question: qa[i],
                            value: 2,
                            gpValue: qa[i].qId,
                            title: qa[i].qChoiceB,
                            onSelected: userChooseAnswer,
                          )
                        : SizedBox(),
                    qa[i].qChoiceC != ""
                        ? ExamRadioButton(
                            question: qa[i],
                            value: 3,
                            gpValue: qa[i].qId,
                            title: qa[i].qChoiceC,
                            onSelected: userChooseAnswer,
                          )
                        : const SizedBox(),
                    qa[i].qChoiceD != ""
                        ? ExamRadioButton(
                            question: qa[i],
                            value: 4,
                            gpValue: _radioGroupValue,
                            title: qa[i].qChoiceD,
                            onSelected: userChooseAnswer,
                          )
                        : SizedBox(),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0, right: 10.0),
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                  Radius.circular(10.0),
                ),
                color: Colors.amberAccent,
              ),
              // width: 60,
              child: Text(
                  '${qa[i].qPayMark}${qa[i].qPayMark == 1 ? " mark" : " marks"}'),
            )
          ],
          alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
        );
      },
    );
  }

void userChooseAnswer(ExamQuestionModel eqm, int value, int gpValue) {
print("Somebody Choose $value in $gpValue");
setState(() {
  gpValue = value;
});
print("Somebody Choose $value in $gpValue");
var examAnswer = context.read<ExamProvider>();
var answer = StudentAnswerDetail(
  sectionId: widget.section.ecId,
  questionId: eqm.qId,
  choiceIndex: value,
  isCorrect: eqm.qTrueIndex == value,
  totalMarks: eqm.qTrueIndex == value ? eqm.qPayMark : 0,
  answerAt: DateTime.now().toString(),
);

examAnswer.addOrUpdateAnswer(answer);
```

}

```
const List<IconData> answerIcon = [
  FontAwesomeIcons.a,
  FontAwesomeIcons.b,
  FontAwesomeIcons.c,
  FontAwesomeIcons.d,
];

class ExamRadioButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final int value;
  final ExamQuestionModel question;
  final int gpValue;
  final String title;
  final Function onSelected;
  const ExamRadioButton({
    Key? key,
    required this.value,
    required this.gpValue,
    required this.title,
    required this.onSelected,
    required this.question,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RadioListTile<int>(
      title: Text("$title $gpValue $value"),
      value: value, //anser index 1, 2 ,3,4
      groupValue: gpValue, // qestionId;
      onChanged: (value) => onSelected(question, value, gpValue),
      dense: true,
      secondary: Icon(
        answerIcon[value - 1],
        size: 16,
      ),
      contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(1.0),
      controlAffinity: ListTileControlAffinity.trailing,
      toggleable: true,
      selected: gpValue == value,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: The problem is you are using statlesswidget so it does't change the state of the widget.

Comment: stateless widget was call in statefull widget [ExamRadioButton] was just a component

Answer (score 1):

You can follow this snippet, the issue was with group value and callback,

```dart
class Ag extends StatefulWidget {
  const Ag({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Ag> createState() => _AgState();
}

class _AgState extends State<Ag> {
  int _gpValue = 4;
  void userChooseAnswer(int? value, int? gpValue) {
    print("Somebody Choose $value in $gpValue");
    if (value != null) {
      _gpValue = value;
      setState(() {});
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          ExamRadioButton(
            key: const ValueKey("item 0"),
            gpValue: _gpValue,
            onSelected: userChooseAnswer,
            title: "A",
            value: 0,
          ),
          ExamRadioButton(
            key: const ValueKey("item 1"),
            gpValue: _gpValue,
            onSelected: userChooseAnswer,
            title: "2",
            value: 4,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ExamRadioButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final int value;
  // final ExamQuestionModel question;
  final int gpValue;
  final String title;
  final Function(int?, int?) onSelected;
  const ExamRadioButton({
    Key? key,
    required this.value,
    required this.gpValue,
    required this.title,
    required this.onSelected,
    // required this.question,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RadioListTile<int>(
      title: Text("$title "),
      value: value, //anser index 1, 2 ,3,4
      groupValue: gpValue, // qestionId;
      onChanged: (value) {
        onSelected(value, gpValue);
      },
      dense: true,
      selected: gpValue == value,
    );
  }
}
```